# Repeating an element on UML diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have the class diagram with the class repeated on it twice. What does it mean?

For examle, model represents the tree of nodes. Parent node aggregates child-nodes. Are these diagrams mean the same?

[image: UML. Class diagram]

I have several options:

1. The graphic element on diagram is a link to model element. So, rectangles with the same name refer to the same model element. Diagrams mean the same thing.
2. The graphic element within the diagram presents the unique model element. So, there are two `Node2` classes within the model, whatever did author meant.
3. The graphic element within the diagram presents the unique model element. Two rectangles with the same name means two classes `Node2`, but it is not well-formed model.

Is it specified in the [UML Standard](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this two diagrams are semantically the same. Both elements in second diagram are representing the same (one) class. You can see that in the specification of UML itself. When it would make difficult to connect some nodes (like Element or Classifier), it is repeated on the diagram.

In other words, option 1 is correct.

Comment: I always thought that UML restricts the use of the very same element in the same diagram since the namespace is not mandatory and thus it may not be clear then the two lower `Node2`s are actually the same element. (Enterprise Architect does not allow this to be done and only in later versions the introduced something weird to construct it though.) However, when I browsed through the specs I could not find an indicator for my assumption. Strange. I would always vote for the lower to be an illegal presentation.

Comment: And yes, I remember having seen such duplication in the specs too.

Comment: Well, I would actually discourage such approach as there's huge risk of error during design stage. Yet the semantic is clear. As for lack of namespaces, if it might lead to ambiguity you have to add them, regardless if the element exists once or more on the diagram @ThomasKilian

Comment: Thank you.

"You can see that in the specification of UML itself."

Could you please point the exact place in the specification?

Comment: P. 372 see the use of `RedefinableElement`.